# Validate application to access the database

Tags: oracle, security, role, application-design, delphi

I need some help for my issue I will explain.

We have a delphi application named for instance App.exe. We use oracle database with our application.

I would like to allow just my App.exe (my valid application that was built by me) and not other App.exe that some other developer created.

At this moment we are signing our App.exe with a public CA.

So, is there any way to say to oracle to verify the App.exe and allow the connection since it is "official"? Maybe a trigger? Or validating the certificate signed?

Thanks!!

Diego

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007308/allowing-oracle-db-login-only-to-specific-application May be useful for you.

Comment: Why?  What problem are you trying to solve?  A password protected role or a login trigger that looks at some information you've set in the context would provide some protection.  But a real attacker could just decompile your source to find the password and observe a session to see what values are being set so they would be mostly useless against real attackers and might create annoyances for users.  If you are really concerned that data is accessed only through a particular application, you'd be better off with a three tier architecture where you control the database and your app is a service.

Comment: You cannot control the client. In any situation.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what safeguards you put in place on the server side, it will always be possible for a client to fake a connection. This is an inherent limitation of the client-server model - the server can only gather information about the client by querying the client, and the client can always be configured to lie.

You cannot completely protect against this without the use of middleware. If you only allow the middleware to connect directly to the database e.g. by ip blocking, then you can have complete control of what commands can and can't be sent to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @JustinCave is right. Grant permission on user role based for application and restrict others from viewing. Even you can restrict it from particular ip also and only allowing user from particular ip to access this with proper credentials.

Moreover if database credentials are on server side there is nothing to worry unless your server is not secure. separating your presentation layer from business and data access layer.

Comment: My real problem right now is that developers can compile a new App.exe, insert some break point, or set some value in the code and compile and start using and manipulating the App.exe because they "changed" the App.exe. So the idea is just permit the App.exe that is one official. About the user roles, my users that login in the system their username and password are stored in a table, they are not database users, just application users. Password for database connection is hardcoded but we are looking to change it.

Comment: In that case place database credentials on other system for example remote server and make api call by username and password. If its validated then get credentials from server and use that for further communication. This will solve your problem as authentication can only be done who has credentials of api.